# Java Selenium drag and drop to canvas does not work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

So I am trying to automate drag and drop. My stack is Java + Selenium. And seems like this is impossible. Need a help if you had experience working with the same set up.
[Page with the Canvas element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxwTz.png)

The area I must drag and drop picture is inside Canvas. It only works if user drops it into the blue area. This blue area can not be mapped. There only canvas elements in the page html. (class="lower-canvas" and class="upper-canvas " in the picture). Blue area is in the midle of the canvas (by height and width).

I tried all the methods listed in the internet and all the methods Chat GPT gives to me. Listing only two that do smth in my opinion.

This method seems to drag and drop at least somewhere cuz I see the error on the UI: "This is not a valid placement". I give it picture element and one of the canvases, result is the same.

```
public void dragDropAxis(By ByFrom, By ByTo) {
        WebElement LocatorFrom = driver.findElement(ByFrom);
        WebElement LocatorTo = driver.findElement(ByTo);

        final String java_script = "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe"
                + "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun"
                + "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(for"
                + "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea"
                + "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev"
                + "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);"
                + "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('"
                + "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit("
                + "'drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(java_script, LocatorFrom, LocatorTo);
        sleep(2000);
    }
```

```
By uploadedPhotoEl = By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'yearbookavenue')]");
        By topCanvas = By.id("fabricCanvasId");
        // By topCanvas = By.xpath("//*[@id='fabricCanvasId']/following-sibling::canvas");
        By zoomInput = By.xpath("//input[@type='number']");
        sleep(5000);
        WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(topCanvas);
        Point canvasPoint = canvas.getLocation();
        Dimension canvasSize = canvas.getSize();
        WebElement uploadedPhoto = driver.findElement(uploadedPhotoEl);
        Point uploadedPhotoPoint = uploadedPhoto.getLocation();
        Dimension uploadedPhotoSize = uploadedPhoto.getSize();
```

This is how I calculate the middle of the canvas. All this calculating seems to work. I see the numbers in the debug mode.

```
actions.moveToElement(uploadedPhoto)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .clickAndHold(uploadedPhoto)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .moveByOffset(400, 300)
                .moveByOffset(400, 300)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .release().build().perform();
```

This is the second method I tried to use to drop into the calculated coordinates. But the thing is - it fails even I give .moveByOffset(1, 1) or any other numbers.
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds

Please, write your thoughts if it can be automated at all? Or maybe you had such a case and managed to solve the problem.

Thanks a lot beforehand.

Comment: I would try with: Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.dragAndDropBy(element, xoffset, yoffset).build().perform();  (might take a bit to hack out the offset numbers)